# InDesign: Automatic change character color of running headers if they have background?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, grep

I have been looking to solve this problem:
I am designing a book with many pages printed with different colors. Is there any way to make the running header change character color depending on weather it has color underneath it? May it be a GREP search for a text box that has % of color to overprint, or something like that? Othervise I have to unlock the header and manually assign a stile on every page with a background?

Thank you

Comment: Forget GREP. GREP is not magic. With GREP, you cannot search for "text boxes" (it only works on text), and neither for "color underneath text"  (that is just not possible with InDesign - imagine there is a photograph 'under' the text!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want multiple colours, or just switch the header from one to another? If you're only looking at two variations, you could always make two master pages: one with a dark header and one with a lighter one. Then use the Pages palette to select all the pages with the header on a solid colour, and apply the light master to them in one go.